# SQL query to get album count for all categories of albums in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to show `AlbumCategories` with count of `Albums` it has for each categories as show below.

Desired result:

```
Sports(2)
Education(3)
Community(0)
Something(0)
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    AC.ACID, MAX(AC.Name) as Name,
    COUNT(*) as Frequency 
FROM 
    Album A
INNER JOIN 
    AlbumCategories AC ON A.ACID = AC.ACID
GROUP BY 
    AC.ACID
```

This query only returns `AlbumCategories` which have albums sample output of above query

```
Sports(2)
Education(3)
```

Table **AlbumCategories**:

```
ACID    Name
1       Sports
2       Education
3       Community
4       Something
```

Table **Albums**:

```
AID     ACID    Name
1       1       Footbal season 2015
2       1       Footbal season 2016
3       2       Album one
4       2       Album Two
5       2       Album Three
```

Table **AlbumsPhotos**:

```
PID     AID Image
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use `RIGHT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` pulls only the matching records between the joined tables. Count the column from `Album` table dont use `*`

**Schema setup**

```
CREATE TABLE AlbumCategories
    ([ACID] int, [Name] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO AlbumCategories
    ([ACID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Sports'),
    (2, 'Education'),
    (3, 'Community'),
    (4, 'Something');


CREATE TABLE albums
    ([AID] int, [ACID] int, [Name] varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO albums
    ([AID], [ACID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Footbal season 2015'),
    (2, 1, 'Footbal season 2016'),
    (3, 2, 'Album one'),
    (4, 2, 'Album Two'),
    (5, 2, 'Album Three');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT AC.ACID,
       AC.NAME       AS NAME,
       Count(A.ACID) AS Frequency
FROM   albums A
       RIGHT JOIN AlbumCategories AC
               ON A.ACID = AC.ACID
GROUP  BY AC.ACID,
          AC.NAME
```

**Result :**

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ ACID ║   NAME    ║ Frequency ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║    1 ║ Sports    ║         2 ║
║    2 ║ Education ║         3 ║
║    3 ║ Community ║         0 ║
║    4 ║ Something ║         0 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: I meant using RIGHT JOIN get me all records with Frequency 1 for each record.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` may give you `1`, but that's not what this answer suggests you use.  Read the answer more closely.

Comment: @Learning - That could be because you are still using `*` count aggregate. Added Demo

Comment: Thank You. It works and you pointer out few mistakes i was doing.